How to remove same name package that the result of 'colcon build' in another workspace?
I'm trying to follow the tutorials for working with ROS2 jazzy in Ubuntu24.04.1 LTS.
background:
I have executed Creating a workspace, after Using colcon to build packages of tutorials.
Then turtlesim and examples existed in same workspace ros2_ws/src, and 'colcon build' was succeeded.
But I'd like to only build turtlesim. Then I remove directory of turtlesim from ros2_ws/src, and create a new workspace ros2_ws2/src.
Result:
'colcon build' was succeeded but the following warning occurred.
I guess the result of previous package remain in system.
How to remove previous turtlesim package from my system?
[0.149s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_core.package_selection:Some selected packages are already built in one or more underlay workspaces:
        'turtlesim' is in: /opt/ros/jazzy
If a package in a merged underlay workspace is overridden and it installs headers, then all packages in the overlay must sort their include directories by workspace order. Failure to do so may result in build failures or undefined behavior at run time.
If the overridden package is used by another package in any underlay, then the overriding package in the overlay must be API and ABI compatible or undefined behavior at run time may occur.

If you understand the risks and want to override a package anyways, add the following to the command line:
        --allow-overriding turtlesim

This may be promoted to an error in a future release of colcon-override-check.
Starting >>> turtlesim
Finished <<< turtlesim [17.4s]

Summary: 1 package finished [17.5s]

